# Why does a blank line in a text file cause java.util.NoSuchElementException?

Tags: java, readfile

If you have a text file:

```
AAA:123:123:AAAA
BBB:456:456:BBBB
```

At first when there is no blank line in the text file and you read and retrieve data. Everything is fine.

When you write the file into a new file and replaces the data or update

```
AAA:9993:9993:AAAA
BBB:456:456:BBBB
-------- This is a blank line-----------
```

After this happens, NoSuchElementException will pop out. If the blank line is not removed, the error will always pop out.

```
try {
File fileCI = new File("CI.txt");
FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(fileCI);
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter); 

for (Customer ci : custList){
if (inputUser.equals(ci.getUserName()) && inputPass.equals(ci.getPassword())) {
    ci.setCardNo(newCardNo);
    ci.setCardType(newCardType);
}
    String text = ci.getRealName() + ";" + ci.getUserName() + ";" + ci.getPassword() + ";" + ci.getAddress() + ";" + ci.getContact() + ";" + ci.getcardType() + ";" + ci.getcardNo() + System.getProperty("line.separator");                                
    bw.write(text);
}
    bw.close();
    fileWriter.close();
}
catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

if I dont add the System.getProperty("line.separator"); The String will be added and everything will be combined together into a line without a new separator. But this separator adds a blank line at the end of the text file. Is there anything I can do to avoid this problem?

Should I solve at the place where I read the file? Or solve it at the place where I write the file into a new file.

```
    try {
        Scanner read = new Scanner(file);

        read.useDelimiter(";|\n");
        String tmp = "";
        while (read.hasNextLine()){
            if (read.hasNext()){
                custList.add(new Customer(read.next(), read.next(), read.next(), read.next(), read.next(), read.next(), read.next()));
            } else {
                break;
            }
        }
        read.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Edit: This above read works perfectly now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you reach at the end of file(EOF) where there is no remaining line and you still trying to read line . So you getting NoSuchElementException(if no line was found ).

Try this:

```
String tmp="";
while (reader.hasNextLine()){  
   tmp = s.nextLine();
   // then do something

}
```

I think you dont have to use `\n` in delimiter. Since we are using `scanner.hasNextLine()`. If you want to use `scanner.next()`. Then

```
read.useDelimiter(";|\n");
```

Above line should be:

```
read.useDelimiter(";|\\n");// use escape character.
```

And loop this way.

```
while(s.hasNext()){ 
    //do something.
}
```

Comment: So how do I let the reading of file to know its EOF and not to try and retrieve more information?

Comment: @John See my answer above.

Comment: Look at my edited post.. is it right that I did it that way? And what I got was.. I only inserted the middle part but not the 1st and 3rd line

Comment: @John Why you comparing `temp` with `read.nextLine()`. `temp` is empty string whereas `read.nextLine()` may have some String.

Comment: If the nextLine is empty, I would like it to stop, so I thought comparing tmp is the right thing to do

Comment: I did an edit, removing the comparison. So now it only stores my 2nd and 3rd line into the arraylist but not the first one.

Comment: @John See I made edit . And if it doesnt help you then post your file contents.

Comment: I did the above edit in my original post. It works very well now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @John There is no use of if else block in your while loop .It is redundant try removing it and running your code.

Comment: I removed it but the program just hangs there.. So that is why I added the break